# Loop inside of a loop, in React JSX

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, jsx

I am trying to render in react, jsx, a loop inside of a loop
Like bellow:

```
{this.state.ans.map(function(item) {
    return (
        {this.state.quest.map(
            function(item1) {return (item1)}
        )}        
        {item}
    )
})}
```

This does not work any other suggestions

Comment: Is that everything inside the render? What are you trying to return in the end? Usually you want to do all the loops and return the result of all the loops at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the wrapping div in your first `map` statement:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.ans.map(item =>
        <div> // this div was missing
          {this.state.quest.map(quest => quest)}
          {item}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Great, yes that was the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
render(){
    return (
        .
        .
        .
        {this.state.ans.map((item) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.state.quest.map((item1) => { 
                           return (item1); 
                        }
                    )}        
                   {item}
               </div>
            );
        })}
    );
}
```

Basically the idea is that, you should return a single element - in my example a `div` (with the latest react version you don't have to). And moreover, use lambdas in order for `this` to reference the correct context.

If you do not use ES6, you can add the following statement at the beginning of the `render` method:

```
var that = this;
```

and use `that` afterwards with the `function(){}` syntax inside the `return`.