# adding new lines in react jsx element array values

Tags: reactjs

trying to add new line when display values in react.
Can somebody tell me what am I missing?
here is my code

```
const qList = qs.map(
    (question, idx) => (<div key={idx}>{idx>0?<hr />:<span />}{idx+1 + '. ' + 
    question.split('\n').map((item) => {return (item);})}</div>)
  );

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      { qList }
    </div>
  );
```

**question data**:
this is line first line.\nThe second\n and this is third
**expected result**:
this is line first line.
The second
and this is third
**What I get**:
this is line first line.,The second, and this is third

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632781/loop-inside-of-a-loop-in-react-jsx)

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

```
const qList = qs.map((question, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          {idx>0?<hr />:<span />}
          {<span>
            {idx+1 + '. '}
          </span>}
          {
            question.split('\n').map(item =>(
              <span>
                {item}
                <br />
              </span>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      ));

return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      { qList }
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Application extends React.Component {
render() {
  let qlist = ["this is line first line.\nThe second\n and this is third"];
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      { 
        qlist.map((qs, idx) => (
          <div key={idx}>
            {
              qs.split("\n").map(item => (
                <span>
                  {item}
                  <br/>
                </span>
              ))
            }
          </div>
         ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not understand `\n`. Use `<br />` instead.

This should help:

```
question.split('\n').map((item) => {return <span> {item} + <br /></span>;})}</div>)
```

Comment: I tried that also, but no luck.can you update with a code example?

Comment: thanks for the help. but it's not working. giving <br /> instead of new line